# How to use Date Only as data type in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, orm, type-conversion

When I use Entity Framework as an ORM, for each `Date` data type in my SQL Server DB it creates a `DateTime` data type `y` in my MVC project.

I mean, for each table in my DB, in my MVC project is auto-generated the code for this class using `DateTime` data type, but I don't need time, only the date.

So my question is: what can I do to declare this field as `Date` only data type or How is commonly handled this situation?.

```
public partial class Employee
{        
    public int Id_Employee { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> B_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SSN_L4 { get; set; }
    public string Phone_N { get; set; }
    public string Adress_L1 { get; set; }
    public string Adress_City { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Fundamentally the lack of a date-only .NET type hampers this...

Comment: @Backs: Both the question and the answers there are to do with code-first date field creation; this is to do with a database-first situation. Addtionally, those answers all stick with `DateTime` as the type. I don't think any of the answers there will help the OP.

Comment: I don't know how to 'solve' it, but ensuing problems are eased by making sure from the start to clear the time part of each date.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following

```
[Column(TypeName="Date")]
public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
```